# importing-a-sql-db-dump-postgres11 pgadmin4

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I have a SQL dump file: C:\Users\Rayyan\Desktop\dump_2.sql.

I have been trying to import this for so long. I am using pgadmin 4, and since I could find nothing in that GUI to help, I tried using Windows command prompt.

I created my new database "wecudos" in pgadmin4.

Then tried the following command in windows command prompt:

> psql wecudos < C:\Users\Rayyan\Desktop\dump_2.sql

according to the specified format:

> psql dbname < dumpfile

This is not working, please help, I have also added a screenshot of the error/data I entered, thanks!

[image]

Comment: Do you know exactly how this dump file was created?  "pg_dump", "pg_dumpall", or something else?  And what options were used?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin>psql -U postgres dbname < D:\testdump.sql
```

or

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin>psql -U postgres dbname < D:\testdump.sql
```

Comment: I edited check now